# Probability of obtaining at least 1 face card from 3 draws with a given formula

Tags: probability

I'm being given the following formula: () =  − (~)

I'm being given an example to use the formula, which is the following: "Probability of obtaining at least 1 face card (so $12$ out of $52$) by drawing $3$ cards out of a $52$-card deck." And I'm instructed to use the above formula as it is easier to calculate the probability of obtaining 0 face cards ((~)) and then using the above formula instead of taking into account the case "$1$ face card", "$2$ face cards" and "$3$ face cards" because of the "AT LEAST" in the example given.

I don't have any way to confirm if I applied the formula correctly because I don't know how to apply the "drawing 3 cards" part, so please tell me what I did wrong/right:

Probability of drawing $0$ face cards:

$\frac{40}{52}$ because there's $12$ face cards in a deck
By the formula, () =  − (~)
$$P(A) = 1 - \frac{40}{52} $$
$$P(A) = 0.23076923076$$

Conclusion would be: The probability of getting at least $1$ face card by drawing $3$ cards out of a $52$-card deck is $0.23076923076$.

This doesn't seem correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You computed $P(\text{~}A)$ incorrectly.

The first card drawn has to be a non-face card with probability $\frac{40}{52}$

Then that card is eliminated so the next card has to be a non-face card with probability $\frac{39}{51}$

Then that card is eliminated so the final card has to be a non-face card with probability $\frac{38}{50}$

All together,

$$P(A)=1-\left(\frac{40}{52}\cdot\frac{39}{51}\cdot\frac{38}{50}\right)\approx0.5529$$